# How to do if-else on Regex based on user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regex expression. What I'm basically trying to do is validate a password field.

Conditions:
1. Minimum value is 6 characters.

2. If value is 6 characters but not more than 9 characters, it should contain at least 1 number and 1 letter (alphanumeric and spaces allowed).
3. If value is more than 10 characters, it can be letters only. No need for a number like the condition #2. (Alphanumeric and spaces allowed)

I am doing this in a RegularExpressionValidator ASP.NET Control.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that this is used in an asp:Wizard control and the maximum is 50 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the possibilities of the control you used because I'm not a ASP.NET developer.

This is the regex that should work but I think you should use another option by checking the value in code. This regex is hard to understand and hard to maintain:

```
(?=(?:^.{10,}$|(?<issmall>^.{6,9}$)))(?(issmall)(?=^.*\d)(?=^.*[a-zA-Z]).*|.*)
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/hBfGas)

Output:

```
0123456789: True
Hello1: True
Helloa: False
123456: False
Thats a very long text that should be accepted.: True
```

Comment: This does not necessarily work on the control but I applied it on a js function that validates the input and works like charm. Thank you!

Comment: Another note, this solution has PHP syntax needed to run so adjustments must be done depending on what language is used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to use a combination of asp RegularExpressionValidator and a CustomValidator. Your Regex validator can check for the minimum length by using something like:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="regexPassword" runat="server" 
Enabled="true" ControlToValidate="passwordTexbox" 
ValidationExpression"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){6,}$"
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator id="customValidatorPassword" runat="server" 
OnServerValidate="PasswordValid" 
ControlToValidate="passwordTexbox">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

And then your server validation can be something like this:

```
PasswordValid(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    //Check if an integer was entered if the length is <= 9
    int integer;
    if(passwordTextbox.Text.Length <= 9 && Int32.TryParse(passwordTextbox.Text, out integer))
    {
         args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else if (passwordTextbox.Text.Length > 9)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else 
    {
         args.IsValid = false;
    }

}
```

You can set the error messages on the server code or in the asp controls.